# Dealing arrays with hamcrest and rest assured

Tags: hamcrest, rest-assured

I can't figure out how to create the code using hamcrest to check an array inside array having these properties.

(Imagine this as it has multiple entries with different data)

```
 {
        "mobilenum": "+6519829340",
        "firstname": "Allen",
        "lastname": "Edwards",
        "location": "Singapore"
    }
```

If I use this:

```
 .body("smsentries.mobilenum", contains(equalTo("+6519829340")));
```

it returns that it does exist but how can I put more checks that the object it has found also has the same firstname, lastname and location?

I also think that this is wrong:

```
 .body("smsentries.mobilenum", contains(equalTo("+6519829340")))
      .and()
 .body("smsentries.firstname", contains(equalTo("Allen"));
```

As what I understand here is that it searches the array if the array contains mobilenum equal to what is provided and if the array contains the name "Allen"

What I needed to is to find the array having the mobilenum equal to "+6519829340" and having the firstname equalto "Allen".

Do you guys and gals have any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I needed to is to find the array having the mobilenum equal to
>   "+6519829340" and having the firstname equalto "Allen".

You can make use of the "find" method:

```
.body("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '+6519829340' }.firstname", equalTo("Allen")
.body("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '+6519829340' }.lastname", equalTo("Edwards").
```

As you see you're essentially duplicating the path expression in the two cases so to improve this we can make use of [root paths](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Root_path):

```
.root("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '+6519829340' }").    
.body("firstname", equalTo("Allen")
.body("lastname", equalTo("Edwards").
```

You can also parameterize root paths:

```
.root("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '%s' }").    
.body("firstname", withArgs("+6519829340"), equalTo("Allen")
.body("lastname", withArgs("+6519829340"), equalTo("Edwards").
.body("firstname", withArgs("+12345678"), equalTo("John")
.body("lastname", withArgs("+12345678"), equalTo("Doe").
```

Comment: Hi johan! HThank you! But I do have one other issue. What would be the syntax if first name equals xand last name equals y, then number should be z. Another example from the data above it has the same data except for on field. How do I combine conditions?

Comment: I think you should create a new question for that and mark this as answered. I can answer the new questions as well if you leave a comment (with link to the new question) here.

Comment: I guess you're right. Here's the new link for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706158/json-arrays-with-duplicate-items-with-hamcrest-and-restassured Thank you!

Comment: What is `it` (`it.mobilenum`) supposed to be? A param as of `JsonPath.param`? But then, how do you get a `ValidatableResponse` from the `JsonPath`?