# JSON arrays with duplicate items with Hamcrest and RestAssured

Tags: hamcrest, rest-assured

As a follow up question for my question in [Dealing arrays with hamcrest and rest assured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520621/dealing-arrays-with-hamcrest-and-rest-assured)

How can I use hamcrest with restassured so that I can test

```
{
    "mobilenum": "+6519829340",
    "firstname": "Allen",
    "lastname": "Edwards",
    "location": "Singapore"
    "outbound": "YES"
    "count" : 15
}, 
{
    "mobilenum": "+6519829340",
    "firstname": "Allen",
    "lastname": "Edwards",
    "location": "Singapore"
    "outbound": "NO"
    "count" : 9
}
```

That there exist two types of data, one containing mobilenum, firstname, etc having outbound equal to yes, and the other no.

It would be like having two objects having the same properties except the outbound property.

An answer by John, from the previous question is this:

```
 .root("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '%s' }").    
 .body("firstname", withArgs("+6519829340"), equalTo("Allen")
 .body("lastname", withArgs("+6519829340"), equalTo("Edwards").
 .body("firstname", withArgs("+12345678"), equalTo("John")
 .body("lastname", withArgs("+12345678"), equalTo("Doe").
```

I don't know how to add something like withArgs("Allen") and ("Edwards) .equalTo("outbound")

---

### **UPDATE**

What I hope to happen is like this:

```
 for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : o.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals("smsentries")) {
        JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement elementJSON : array) {
            SMSEntry smsEntry = mapper.readValue(elementJSON.toString(), SMSEntry.class);
                if (smsEntry.getMobilenum().equals("+6519829340") && 
                        smsEntry.getOutbound().equals("YES")) {
                            assertThat(smsEntry.getLocation(), equalTo("Singapore"));
                            assertThat(smsEntry.getCount(), equalTo(15));
                        }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I have a mobile number equal to +6519829340 and is outbound, assert that the location is in Singapore and has count of 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and that the list of users(?) is called `smsentries` as it was in the previous question) you could do like this:

```
.root("smsentries.findAll { it.mobilenum == '%s' }").    
.body("firstname", withArgs("+6519829340"), contains("Allen", "Allen"))
.body("lastname", withArgs("+6519829340"), contains("Edwards", "Edwards"))
.body("outbound", withArgs("+6519829340"), containsInAnyOrder("YES", "NO"))
// Additional body matchers
```

**Update after clarification**

> If I have a mobile number equal to +6519829340 and is outbound, assert
>   that the location is in Singapore and has count of 15.

You can do like this:

```
.root("smsentries.find { it.mobilenum == '+6519829340' && it.outbound == 'YES'}").    
.body("location", equalTo("Singapore"))
.body("count", equalTo(9))
```

Comment: Hi Johan, I think I understand what you are trying to do but I may have failed in giving more of a concise description of my issue. I have added a new field in my json to make it more clear.

Comment: I just tried the code and I had to add parenthesis to each conditions: .root("smsentries.find { (it.mobilenum == '+6519829340') && (it.outbound == 'YES'})").  Is that normal?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to use parenthesis.